# How to check for Accept header in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http-accept-header

I have an API end-point in Spring Boot, let's say `/pokemons`. For `GET /pokemons` I want to have two different responses. The first one is JSON, and the second one is Microsoft Excel file. As far as I know this is done the Accept header. But when writing a Spring Boot controller with `@GetMapping` annotation there is only `produces` and `consumes`. Is there any build-in way to work according to the `Accept` header?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces())?  "... of which must be chosen via content negotiation against the "acceptable" media types of the request. Typically those are extracted from the "Accept" header"

Comment: produces is exactly what you want. Write 2 methods for the same URL with a different produces value. One for JSON (or whatever) and one for Excel.